# How to reference a pilot study in an academic paper written in a foreign language?

Tags: paper-submission, anonymity

I presented a paper at a conference and later the conference published it in the (non-academic) conference journal. It was done in a foreign language. Afterwards, I used the same idea but a different data set, different references, expanded the methodology and wrote a separate paper (in English). I want to submit this paper to an academic journal but I am puzzled about how should I reference it while keeping the anonymity of the paper. If I cite it like any other paper, it would be clear who the author is as it would be the only non-English reference.

Comment: Are you the only author appearing in the non-academic jounral?

Comment: Are you sure the academic journal you would like to submit to has a double-blind review?

Comment: I did it together with my professor (I am PhD student), and yes, the academic journal uses a double-anonymized review system.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply anonymize the source (omit it and replace with a comment along the lines of "this reference was omitted in the review version to maintain the integrity of the double blind review process") and once peer review is over but before publication, you put it back in.

Drop a note to the editor if you want to explain what you did with the reference, but this is quite common and won't surprise them. See the related questions about anonymizing papers for peer review, or have at look at [these journal instructions](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/social-science-and-medicine/policies/double-blind-peer-review-guidelines).